# What did I see?

Tags: riddle

> - I saw kings but no kingdom
> - I saw a half dozen lovers but one was left over
> - I saw racism but no one discriminated on color
> - I saw mathematicians but all of them didn't know why they started everything from two
> - All of them lived happily but there was a serious villain among them
> - The more I saw them, the poorer  I became in  my life

**What did I see?**

Comment: This question was answered correctly by Styx. Why there is a bounty on it still ? I am wondering !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it

> Cards?

I saw kings but no kingdom ,

> Four kings no kingdom

I saw a half dozen lovers but one was left over ,

> Based on OP's comment, there are 13 hearts (love) out of which 6 have a pair, leaving one that is "alone"

I saw racism but no one discriminated on color ,

> 4 "races": Spades, Clubs,(black) Hearts and Diamonds(red) - in most games you would group them by "race" and not actual color

I saw mathematicians but all of them didn't knew why they started everything from two,

> The decks start from 2

All of them lived happily but there was a serious villain among them ,

> Based on OP's comment, the Joker

More I saw them , more poorer I became in my life ,

> Gambling problem? The more you see the cards the more money you lose

Comment: The serious villain is the Joker, gambling appears to be correct, the "one left over" may refer to the Ace? If not, maybe something to do with a 5-card hand of poker?

Comment: In card games, it is not that unusual that the card colours have different values (more or less worth), so 'no one discriminated on colour' does not really match.

Comment: @jarnbjo Well I thought it was more common that the suits had different values

Comment: @somebody Sorry, language confusion. My native language uses the same word for 'suit' (in the sense of card suit) and 'colour'.

Comment: Perhaps the half-dozen lovers refers to the fact that there are 13 cards in each suit? - so a half-dozen pairs, with one left over?

Comment: @jarnbjo Out of curiousity, in your native language how are hearts and diamonds (both red) and spades and clubs (both black) described?

Comment: Why "half a dozen" lovers? What are the "mathematicians" that were seen? And the "serious villian" doesn't sound very convincing either. I don't think this is the correct answer. I'm really hoping there is a much better answer than this with much better justifications.

Comment: this is closest answer , serious villain is joker (@somebody) , and lovers is 13 hearts(@puzzledPig) ..

Answer (score 3):

It is

> Chess !

I saw kings but no kingdom

> Two kings (Black and white are there) but there is no kingdom

I saw a half dozen lovers but one was left over

> Black Camel-White Camel, Black Horse-White Horse, Black rook - White Rook, as they are animals and remaining all are considered to be 'humans' who need not be lovers ....that too on a battle field !

I saw racism but no one discriminated on color

> Black and white pieces but no body ever complains on being playing in either pieces (though White has a slight starting edge!!)

I saw mathematicians but all of them didn't knew why they started everything from two

> Usually they start from 2nd square e2 - e4 or d2 - d4 )

All of them lived happily but there was a serious villain among them

> With mutual consent each player can agree for a draw (even without a kill !, of course sometimes) - so that they lived happily. Serious villian could be the time-piece (stop watch, if the game is played professionally), which pressurizes both of them equally !

More I saw them , more poorer I became in my life

> Unless you are a professional player (with a sponsor, of course), if you are only seeing them...it means a waste of time and leads to poorness.

Comment: Eh, I don't like the explanation for the last line.

Comment: What is the camel you're referring to? That's not in any version I've ever heard of...

Comment: The 'Bishop' (standard notation 'B' ) is usually referred as Camel in 'Asiatic' countries !

Comment: Could the "More I saw them" relate to opposing pieces, and the poorer be the loss of your own?

Comment: Good one @BM- it is quite possible !

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so Ill just post these two explanations here

I saw a half dozen lovers but one was left over

> kings and queens, hearts, clubs, diamonds = 6 but in pinochle the queen of
>  spades can match up with the jack of diamonds leaving king spade out.

All of them lived happily but there was a serious villain among them ,

> Again queen of spades but in the game hearts, shes worth 13 points=bad

All the rest looked good to me.